# Add name + code to buffer if not exist?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE item(
code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY(name, code)) ENGINE = INNODB

CREATE TABLE buffer(
code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(name, code)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

How can I do the following using only one statement: `if name+code doesn't exist in any table then add them on buffer.`

Comment: Union, and coalesce seems like it would work. or maybe a subselect or join instead of coalesce

Comment: Why not buffer within the `item` table, using an additional column that flags whether the record is "buffered" or not?

Comment: I prefer not to do this, mainly because the data in the buffer table must be verified and the verification takes time. I decided not to store invalid data on the main table.

Comment: Why does the time required for verification affect where you store the data?

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` statement as a sub query, like this:

```
INSERT INTO buffer (code, name)
SELECT 1,'myname' FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM item WHERE code=1 and name='myname'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM buffer WHERE code=1 and name='myname'
)
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ecc66/1